# image processing/upload issue SQL/PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, warnings

I am having an issue uploading an image to my server, any help would be greatly appreciated. See below:

```
$sql = "SELECT avatar FROM users WHERE username='$log_username' LIMIT 1";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
$avatar = $row[0];
if($avatar != ""){
       $picurl = "../user/$log_username/$avatar"; 
    if (file_exists($picurl)) { unlink($picurl); }
    else if(!file_exists($picurl)){
              mkdir($picurl, 0777,true);
           }
}
$moveResult = move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, "../user/$log_username/$db_file_name");
if ($moveResult != true){
    echo "ERROR: File not uploaded. Try again.";
unlink($fileTmpLoc); // Remove the uploaded file from the PHP temp folder
 exit();
}
```

The issue I am having is with
**$moveResult = move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, "../user/$log_username/$db_file_name");**

These are the errors that are generating when I try to process the request:

> Warning: move_uploaded_file(../user/test/269941961951.PNG): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/test1/public_html/php_parsers/photo_system.php on line 62
>
> Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpo0OWwN' to '../user/test/269941961951.PNG' in /home/test1/public_html/php_parsers/photo_system.php on line 62

ERROR: File not uploaded. Try again.

I know that it exists in the DIR.

If anyone could help it would be great thanks.

Comment: thanks for your swift reply but yes it does, see below: $avatar_form  = '<form id="avatar_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="php_parsers/photo_system.php">';
 $avatar_form .=   '<h4>Change your avatar</h4>';
 $avatar_form .=   '<input type="file" name="avatar" required>';
 $avatar_form .=   '<p><input type="submit" value="Upload"></p>';
 $avatar_form .= '</form>';

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the rest of what's related to using `move_uploaded_file` array; but make sure the folder has proper permissions to write to it. See the manual also http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Comment: Thanks, I will have another look at the manual, I just can't see what I am doing wrong. is there any way I can link you the scripts related to the array?

Comment: So assuming that the file does exist and the folder /home/test1/public_html/user/test exists,  it's most likely a permissions issue on the folder.